# adding multiple values in object list in web api c#

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I am new to web api and C#. I am creating a function where I am calling values from table which has 33 rows. the query is this:

```
Select * from T_SVRS_Reg_Trans
```

I have created a model where I have put out properties like so:

```
public class UserModel
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string OrgUnit { get; set; }

        public string TDC { get; set; }

        public string CustCode { get; set; }

        public string CustName { get; set; }

        public string DestCode { get; set; }

        public string EMV { get; set; }

        public string Service { get; set; }

        public string SPCCode { get; set; }

        public string SPCode { get; set; }

        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        public int Stage { get; set; }

        public string Cost { get; set; }

        public string SAPUpdate { get; set; }

        public string Active { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I am calling the table values to get added in these properties. My function for that is this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetTableValue")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTableValue()
        {
            try
            {
                UserModel objUserModel = new UserModel();


                ManageUserData ObjManageUserData = new ManageUserData();
                var sqlDataTable = ObjManageUserData.GetTableValue();

                if (sqlDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; (i < sqlDataTable.Rows.Count); i++)
                    {
                        objUserModel.OrgUnit=(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Org_ID"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.TDC = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_TDC_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CustCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CustName = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Name"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.DestCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Dest_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.EMV = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_EMV"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Service = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Service"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SPCCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SPC_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SPCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SP_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Remarks = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Remarks"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Stage = (int)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Stage"]);
                        objUserModel.Cost = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cost_Imp"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SAPUpdate = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SAP_Update_Status"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Active = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_IS_ACTIVE"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CreatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_BY"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CreatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_ON"]);
                        objUserModel.UpdatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_BY"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.UpdatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_ON"]);
                        
                    }
                }
                return Ok(objUserModel);


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Something went wrong");
            }
```

However I am noticing that only the last table value is added to the model and the rest of it is not. I want to add all 33 values in model form to the model mentioned. Is there any way to do this?

PLease help
}

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `objUserModel` each iteration. Create a `new` one inside the loop, add them to a `List<UserModel>`, returning that to your view.

Also consider dropping the archaic Hungarian notation (the "obj" prefix). Also consider using an ORM instead of mapping columns to properties using strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `List` or `Array` of type `UserModel` and adding items into it

```
try
{
    List<UserModel> result = new List<UserModel>();
    ManageUserData ObjManageUserData = new ManageUserData();
    var sqlDataTable = ObjManageUserData.GetTableValue();

    if (sqlDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; (i < sqlDataTable.Rows.Count); i++)
        {
            UserModel objUserModel = new UserModel();
            objUserModel.OrgUnit = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Org_ID"].ToString());
            objUserModel.TDC = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_TDC_Code"].ToString());
            objUserModel.CustCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Code"].ToString());
            objUserModel.CustName = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Name"].ToString());
            objUserModel.DestCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Dest_Code"].ToString());
            objUserModel.EMV = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_EMV"].ToString());
            objUserModel.Service = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Service"].ToString());
            objUserModel.SPCCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SPC_Code"].ToString());
            objUserModel.SPCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SP_Code"].ToString());
            objUserModel.Remarks = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Remarks"].ToString());
            objUserModel.Stage = (int)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Stage"]);
            objUserModel.Cost = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cost_Imp"].ToString());
            objUserModel.SAPUpdate = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SAP_Update_Status"].ToString());
            objUserModel.Active = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_IS_ACTIVE"].ToString());
            objUserModel.CreatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_BY"].ToString());
            objUserModel.CreatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_ON"]);
            objUserModel.UpdatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_BY"].ToString());
            objUserModel.UpdatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_ON"]);
            result.Add(objUserModel);
        }
    }
    return Ok(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Something went wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the collection instead of single object UserModel.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetTableValue")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTableValue()
        {
            try
            {
                ManageUserData ObjManageUserData = new ManageUserData();
                var sqlDataTable = ObjManageUserData.GetTableValue();
                List<UserModel> userModels = new List<UserModel>();
                if (sqlDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; (i < sqlDataTable.Rows.Count); i++)
                    {
                        var objUserModel = new UserModel()
                        objUserModel.OrgUnit = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Org_ID"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.TDC = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_TDC_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CustCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CustName = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Name"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.DestCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Dest_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.EMV = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_EMV"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Service = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Service"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SPCCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SPC_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SPCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SP_Code"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Remarks = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Remarks"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Stage = (int)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Stage"]);
                        objUserModel.Cost = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cost_Imp"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.SAPUpdate = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SAP_Update_Status"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.Active = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_IS_ACTIVE"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CreatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_BY"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.CreatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_ON"]);
                        objUserModel.UpdatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_BY"].ToString());
                        objUserModel.UpdatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_ON"]);
                        userModels.Add(userModels);

                    }
                }
                return Ok(userModels);


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Something went wrong");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are expecting more than one row to be returned, you need to collect the rows as you iterate your result set into some sort of collection/list/array.

Try making a list of your `UserModel`

```
List<UserModel> objUserModels = new List<UserModel>();
```

And then adding each object to the list after each iteration of your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < sqlDataTable.Rows.Count); i++)
{
    var objUserModel = new UserModel();

    objUserModel.OrgUnit=(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Org_ID"].ToString());
    objUserModel.TDC = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_TDC_Code"].ToString());
    objUserModel.CustCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Code"].ToString());
    objUserModel.CustName = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cust_Name"].ToString());
    objUserModel.DestCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Dest_Code"].ToString());
    objUserModel.EMV = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_EMV"].ToString());
    objUserModel.Service = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Service"].ToString());
    objUserModel.SPCCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SPC_Code"].ToString());
    objUserModel.SPCode = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SP_Code"].ToString());
    objUserModel.Remarks = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Remarks"].ToString());
    objUserModel.Stage = (int)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Stage"]);
    objUserModel.Cost = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_Cost_Imp"].ToString());
    objUserModel.SAPUpdate = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_SAP_Update_Status"].ToString());
    objUserModel.Active = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_IS_ACTIVE"].ToString());
    objUserModel.CreatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_BY"].ToString());
    objUserModel.CreatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_CREATED_ON"]);
    objUserModel.UpdatedBy = (sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_BY"].ToString());
    objUserModel.UpdatedOn = (DateTime)(sqlDataTable.Rows[i]["TRT_UPDATED_ON"]);
    
    objUserModels.Add(objUserModel);
    
}
```

And then return your list of objects:

```
return Ok(objUserModels);
```